# Why does Common.Logging in NuGet use .NET Portable?

Tags: .net, msbuild, mono, mscorlib, common.logging

I am using:

- MonoDevelop 7.1
- .NET Framework 4.6.2
- Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205 Thu May 25 09:16:53 UTC 2017) (64-bit)
- No PCL or profiles (to my knowledge)
- msbuild 15.2.0.0 (Thu May 11 17:28:41 UTC 2017)

`<NoStdLib>` is not specified; that is, it's left at its default.
`<TargetFrameworkVersion>` is set to v4.6.2.

When I build in the IDE, I see no warnings or errors. However, when I build the solution with

```
msbuild /v:detailed my.sln
```

I see a few of these messages:

```
  Dependency "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea77
98e, Retargetable=Yes".
      Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

Browsing through the Mono files, all of the following assemblies match the above version and key:

```
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile102/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile19/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile225/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile5/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile92/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile47/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile14/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile24/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile328/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile6/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile158/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile255/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile37/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile240/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile136/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile147/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile42/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile344/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/Profile/Profile336/mscorlib.dll
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.0/mscorlib.dll
```

Other `mscorlib` assemblies either have the wrong version, or have the key token `b77a5c561934e089` instead of `7cec85d7bea7798e`.

My questions are:

- Why is my solution attempting to make a reference to a portable .NET?
- Is there an assembly reference tree tool I can use to find out what the referring culprit is?
- Why is it that this is a non-fatal error, and doesn't even appear in the IDE build output at all?
- Should I make a manual reference to one of these assemblies? If so, which profile?
- If I do not make a reference to one of these assemblies, what are the consequences?
- Does the fact that all of my assemblies are strong-name-signed affect the importance of resolving this error?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Using `monodis --assemblyref`, I see that the problem is `Common.Logging`:

```
Common.Logging.dll
AssemblyRef Table
...
4: Version=2.0.5.0
        Name=mscorlib
        Flags=0x00000100
        Public Key:
0x00000000: 7C EC 85 D7 BE A7 79 8E 

./Common.Logging.Core.dll
AssemblyRef Table
...
1: Version=2.0.5.0
        Name=mscorlib
        Flags=0x00000100
        Public Key:
0x00000000: 7C EC 85 D7 BE A7 79 8E 

./Common.Logging.NLog41.dll
AssemblyRef Table
...
6: Version=2.0.5.0
        Name=mscorlib
        Flags=0x00000100
        Public Key:
0x00000000: 7C EC 85 D7 BE A7 79 8E
```

This, despite my `packages.config` specifically asking for .NET 4.62:

```
  <package id="Common.Logging" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.Core" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.NLog41" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net462" />
```

So I guess this is a bug in `Common.Logging`?

Comment: Redirect `msbuild /v:detailed my.sln` output to a file and share it somewhere. What you posted above does not show enough information and I don't think "it is a bug" yet. Also you should install referenceassemblies-pcl if you haven't, http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin Compiling against PCL profiles is so common for NuGet authors.